# .Net Windows Desktop Cloud Agent

Tags: .net, windows, cloud

I want to build a Windows Application which is connected (somehow via sockets or what ever) to a webservice.

The user installs a cloud agent on its windows machine and can install or change files for that specific application via a cloud hosted management site.

My question: how to build that kind of desktop application? In the end it should work like the Symantec cloud agent. I have really no idea what's the main track to finde software or libs for that use case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use electron which will offer you a nice portable client that could wrap around any client interface you need to use.

As you mentioned, web sockets would be the idea behind the server implementation, so your client tech could be any npm websockets client lib.

On the other hand, you can build the same  app in .NET and look for the websocket4net lib to get more familiar with all limitations, if any.

Good luck!